# how to group by different columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to group by different columns based on year and apply for just same year and finally store the result in a .csv file.

My data and code is :

```
 ISO3  Income_Cat_1980  Income_Cat_1985   DWWC1980 DWWC1985 
 AFG       L                 LM              5        10
 AGO       LM                H               15       25
 ALB       LM                UM              30       40
 ARE       H                 H               40       50 

for i in range (1980,1990,5):
    df=pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("mydata.csv"))
    df=df.groupby("Income_Cat_"+str(i)).sum()
    print df
    df.to_csv('country-surplus'+str(i)+'.csv',index="Income_Cat_"+str(i))
```

my code result is :

```
Income_Cat_1980          DWWC1980   DWWC1985
     H                       40        50
     L                        5        10
     LM                      45        65

Income_Cat_1985           DWWC1980    DWWC1985
     H                       55        75
     LM                       5        10
     UM                      30        40
```

and store the output in different `.csv`file , but I need to calculate the sum of `DWWC1980`and `DWWC1985` based on same year `Income_Cat`, so the result should be:

```
Income_Cat   DWWC1980 DWWC1985  
    H            40       75
    L            5        0
    LM           45       10
    UM           0        40
```

and store output in one `.csv` file.

Comment: Can you show a set of sample calculation steps to arrive at your results table? The numbers don't seem to add up

Comment: Okay, think I might've figured it. You want to retain a complete set of index from the _Income\_Cat_ column and merge the two dataframes, while picking the corresponding values. That is, for _DWWC1980_, you read from the Income_Cat_1980 dataframe and included the missing 'UM' index. Then for the 
 _DWWC1985_ column, you read it off the Income_Cat_1985 dataframe of the corresponding column

Comment: @kerwei, yes. in my code, I have to pick  DWWC1980 value from the first `.csv` and DWWC1985 from the second `.csv` file. since I have more than `70000` index and 30 `column` it is difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shoudld produce the desired output, if i understood the question

```
init = True
for i in range(1980,1990,5):

    _df = df[["Income_Cat_"+str(i), 'DWWC'+str(i)]]
    _df=_df.groupby("Income_Cat_"+str(i)).sum()

    if init:
        out = _df
        init=False
    else:
        out = out.merge(_df, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)

out.fillna(0, inplace=True)
out.index.rename('Income_cat', inplace=True)
```

you can make this slightly more comprehensive, by replacing the first line inside the loop with:

```
_df = df[[a for a in df.columns if str(i) in a]]
```

Comment: thank I think it is working, but if I have other columns like `SSP1980`, `SSP1985`, how can I do the calculation for these columns also?

Comment: you just include them in this line: _df = df[["Income_Cat_"+str(i), 'DWWC'+str(i), 'SSP'+str(i),  '...' + str(i)]]

Answer (score 1):

The code should be looking like this:

```
#You should only be loading the data once
df=pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("mydata.csv"))

dfl = []
for i in range (1980,1990,5):
    temp = df.groupby("Income_Cat_"+str(i))[['DWWC' + str(i)]].sum()
    temp.index.rename('Income_Cat', inplace=True)
    dfl.append(temp)

out = pd.concat(dfl, sort=False).fillna(0)).groupby('Income_Cat').sum()

out.to_csv('country-surplus'+str(i)+'.csv',index="Income_Cat')
```

The output is not exactly the same as you've described, because its index includes all 6 income categories. I don't understand why you'd only need 4 of them, but I hope the snippet is helpful.

Comment: I have 4 indexes, not 6 indexes and I want to see how index related values are changing during the time.

Comment: Got it, I've modified the second-to-last line of my snippet to return the desired output.

Comment: it is not true, it is summing again and returning doubled value.

Answer (score 1):

Guess you need this.

Input:

```
df

    ISO3    Income_Cat_1980     Income_Cat_1985     DWWC1980    DWWC1985
0   AFG     L                   LM                  5           10
1   AGO     LM                  H                   15          25
2   ALB     LM                  UM                  30          40
3   ARE     H                   H                   40          50
```

Use the following code

```
pd.concat([df.groupby('Income_Cat_' + str(year)).sum()['DWWC' + str(year)] 
           for year in range(1980,1986) if 'Income_Cat_' + str(year) in            
           df.columns],1).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Output

```
    DWWC1980    DWWC1985
H   40          75
L   5           0
LM  45          10
UM  0           40
```

Explanation:

`pd.concat([list of series],1)` concatenates `pd.Series` along the indices. If one `pd.Series` (with column name `series1` does not have the index `i` of another the cell in the resulting dataframe gets the value `NaN` so:

```
print(df.loc[i, series1])
```

results in `NaN`. Therefore we use `fillna(0)` to fill `NaN`s with zeros. Casting to integers is the final step to arrive at the desired dataframe